# Using the method in ngclass results Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular

I am using the method in the ngclass which loops in the ngfor.
All the time the method return value changes when the looping does.

But i am getting an error like

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression
>   has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'background_pink'.
>   Current value: 'background_blue'.

The code is like this

component.ts

```
getRandomColor() {
    const changedColor = _.sample(this.colors);
    return changedColor;
}
```

component.html

```
<a href="https://www.leelag.com/tag/laravel" *ngFor="let tag of bookDetails.tags">
<label [ngClass]="['label', 'well', 'well-sm', getRandomColor()]">{{ tag.name }}</label></a>
```

All the time when looping it is displaying the above error.
How to solve this?

Comment: Please see this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14748

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are updating your variable/value within loop code.

***ngFor** will not understand the updated value when it's loop iterate in logic.